# How to get occurence of Specific day within a period

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have two dates let say `2-Mar-16` and `22-Aug-16` and I want to identify that how many times date 25 occurs in this period. How could I create a query like this?

Comment: The key is to do a `group by` based on the column which has that date. Then you can get a `count` of occurrences `having` a specific value.  When you do a group by of a date column, you should handle the time part appropriately - ie, consider it as it is, OR convert to the same time (12.00.00) for all dates etc

Comment: Its a single row data. ex : in 2-Mar16 to 22-Aug-16 date 25 occur 5 time

Comment: display table format and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MONTHS_BETWEEN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm) to get the number of full months between the two dates. If the value is an integer as in your example case, then you need to check whether the given date in the left and right date is 25. If so, add 1 to the result.

If the dates are different, then you need to calculate the floor of `MONTHS_BETWEEN` and check whether between the left and the right date there is a 25th. For example, between 23rd March and 26th April, we have a 25th found by full month search, but since 23 < 25 < 26, we need to add one.

This answer assumes that you have passed the earlier date as left. If this is not accurate, then you must know that the result of `MONTHS_BETWEEN` will be negative and you need to adapt the ideas described here accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The below query will give you the number of occurrence of 25 within a date range. 
Logic i have written inline.

```
select substr(DAT,1,2) numbr,count (substr(DAT,1,2))  --- Filtering only day part of date and counting it
from 
(
--Generating all the dates between 2 dates
select to_date('02-Mar-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL  DAT    
from dual 
connect by level < (select ABS (to_date('02-Mar-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') - to_date('22-Aug-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') )
                    from dual)
)
where substr(DAT,1,2) = 25
group by substr(DAT,1,2);
```